# How to fix nginx error connection refused on AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2

I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error when trying to access nginx on an AWS EC2 instance via the public IP address.

I launched an ubuntu t2.micro EC2 instance and installed nginx on it. Then set inbound rules for port 80(HTTP) and 443(HTTPS) to anywhere[image]

Confirmed that nginx is properly installed by running `systemctl status nginx`

[image]

And `curl localhost`

[image]

With everything looking okay, I should see the nginx page when I hit the EC2 public IP or dns but I get the error page

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by setting ufw rules for http and enabling the service with these commands

```
sudo ufw allow 'Nginx HTTP'
sudo ufw enable
```

After doing this, I was able to reach nginx on port 80